# iOS swift send message after idle for more than 30 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, chat, background-process

i'm fixing chat application bug. When i send message at offline mode and go to background mode. I can only resend the message automatically under 30 seconds after go to background mode.

If i don't go online after 30 seconds. I cannot send the message automatically from background.

Is there any solutions to resend message at the background mode automatically after 30 seconds ? (WhatsApp can do this, so it should be possible)

I'm using this function, maybe it has other function other than this?

```
func beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler handler: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier
```

Comment: After 30 seconds following your app going into the background, your time expires and your app is suspended. To do anything after that, you'd need a push notification.

Comment: You are correct in that some applications can do this. The very limit is 30 seconds. But some companies can go beyond this as they actually have an agreement with Apple regarding this. Don't remember what or how. But remember reading about it when i tried to do a similar solution

Comment: So for the example, WhatsApp make some agreement to Apple to send notification after offline for a several minutes or even hours?